# JQuery File input validation and hiding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, validation

I have a couple of inputs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 file-input">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileOneContainer" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileOne" name="fileOne" class="fileGroup">
            </span>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 file-input">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileTwoContainer" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileTwo" name="fileTwo" class="fileGroup">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have to do my own custom validation for this within Javascript.  Concentrating only on the first input for now, the rules are:

- Cant be empty
- Cant be larger than 2MB
- Must be one of a certain file type

To handle all this, I came up with the following

```
var fileOne = $("#fileOne").val();

if(fileOne.length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    errors.push("- Please upload a document");
} else if($("#fileOne")[0].files[0].size > 2097152) {
    errors.push("- Please upload a file smaller than 2MB");
} else if(  $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/bmp' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/jpeg' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/pjpeg' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/png' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/tiff' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'application/pdf') {
    errors.push("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
}
```

This seems to work, although I imagine it could be improved.

Anyways, I need to now work on the second input.  Initially, this input should be hidden, and only displayed when an add more button is clicked.  Now I do not really want to hide it via css because this can be altered using developers tools.

The rules for the second input are pretty much the same as above, but this input is not required.  This input should only have a value if the first input has a value.  So you shouldnt be able to upload a file to the second input unless you have already uploaded one to the first.

What would be the best way to handle this second input to achieve the affect I am after?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
So I now have this

```
    var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fileGroup');

    for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
        fileInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(event){
            error = validateFile(event);
            errors.push(error);
        });
    };

function validateFile(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var fileLength = input.files[0].length;
    var fileSize = input.files[0].size;
    var fileType = input.files[0].type;

    if(fileLength == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        return("- Please upload a document");
    } else if(fileSize > 2097152) {
        return("- Please upload a file smaller than 2MB");
    } else if(  fileType != 'image/bmp' &&
                fileType != 'image/jpeg' &&
                fileType != 'image/pjpeg' &&
                fileType != 'image/png' &&
                fileType != 'image/tiff' &&
                fileType != 'application/pdf') {
        return("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need the errors to display once the form has been submitted, not when the fileinput changes.  Is there any way to do this without the change event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `accept` attribute set to `".bmp,.jpeg,.jpg,.pjpeg,.png,.tiff,.pdf"` , adding `disabled` to second `input` , setting `disabled` to `false` at `change` event handler of first `input`

```js
var errors = [];

$(document).on("change", "#fileOne, #fileTwo:not(:disabled)", function() {
  console.log(this.files);
  if (this.files[0].size > 2097152) {
    errors.push("- Please upload a file smaller than 2MB");
  };
  if (this.files.length) {
    $("#fileTwo").prop("disabled", false)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 file-input">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileOneContainer" readonly>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileOne" name="fileOne" class="fileGroup" accept=".bmp,.jpeg,.jpg,.pjpeg,.png,.tiff,.pdf">
            </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 file-input">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileTwoContainer" readonly>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileTwo" name="fileTwo" class="fileGroup" accept=".bmp,.jpeg,.jpg,.pjpeg,.png,.tiff,.pdf" disabled="true">
                </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am trying to handle my errors on form submit and not file input changing (because I have many other form elements).  I have updated the OP with what I am attempting.

Comment: @kate_hudson _"trying to handle my errors on form submit and not file input changing (because I have many other form elements)."_ Yes . `errors` appear to be array defined outside of `input` change event ; can access `errors` array at `form` submit ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looping through your inputs and binding an on change event listener to validate the file. That way you don't have to repeat logic and you can grab the context via the event.

```
function validateFile(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var fileSize = input.files[0].size;
    // rest of validation logic here.

}

var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fileGroup')

for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
    fileInputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(event){
        validateFile(event);
    });
};
```

The above starter code should put you in the right direction.

EDIT: If you'd like to do it on submit you can write some code like this:

```
document.forms[index].onsubmit = function() {
    validateFile();
}
```

The index is the index of the form on the page. If there is only one form it most likely is 0.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgautsch/cep7cggr/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have updated the OP with a new problem.  Thanks